# how to pass value from controller to jquery at view in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm learning web programming using framework codeIgniter, I try to send a value from a function in the controller to the query script that is in view.
this is the code on my controller:

```
public function passData(){
        $pass = "the new value";
        return $pass;
    }
```

code in view:

```
<h3 id="tesrow">the value I want change</h3>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn-filter').click(function(){ //button filter event click
            table.ajax.reload(),  //just reload table
            $('#tesrow').text({
                "ajax": {
                    url : "<?php echo site_url("main/passData") ?>",
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried changing the value in the view using a button but it still failed.
thanks for the help

Comment: you have error in script,,, and if it is data table .. encode your data into json ...

Comment: $.text doesnt have an `ajax` option.. how do you come up with that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by reading the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), but this should work for your question:

```
   // The jQuery 
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn-filter').click(function() {
            let $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/myController/myFunction',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',

                beforeSend: function() {
                    $this.prop('disabled', true);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        $this.text(data);
                    }
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $this.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // The PHP function
    public function myFunction() {
        $pass = "the new value";
        echo $pass;
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

at controller

```
   public function passData(){
        $pass = "the new value";
        echo "<p>".$pass."</p>";
    }
```

and at your script..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#btn-filter').click(function(){ 
        $( '#tesrow' ).load( "<?php echo site_url("main/passData") ?>" );
      });
    </script>
```

try this ..

controller is extending class ci_controller .. so you cannot return an string .. in controllers method .. return is use to change the method name ..

Answer (score 0):

use base_url for that in your ajax.these parameter's value will come from controller.

```
function method_name(parameter, parameter, that) {
    $.post(base_url + "controller/method_name", {parameter: parameter_name, parameter: parameter_name}, function (data) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
 1. Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-filter').click(function(){ //button filter event click
        table.ajax.reload(),  //just reload table
        $.ajax({
           url: "<?php echo site_url("main/passData") ?>",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
               $('#tesrow').text(data.result);
           }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

2. controller

```
public function passData(){
    $pass = "the new value";
    echo json_encode(array("result" => $pass));
}
```